# Install older version of Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Is there any way I can go back and install a older version of Cygwin?

Say I want the 1.7.9 version, but the `setup.exe` in the Cygwin website always point to the latest release?

Comment: Are you talking about older versions of cygwin packages, or older versions of the installer (setup.exe)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe will always point to the latest release. The only previous release available at cygwin.com is the ['setup-legacy'](http://www.cygwin.com/win-9x.html) file, which is version 1.5.25 and is compatible with older versions of Windows. Downloading older versions of Cygwin is discouraged because of incompatibility with the latest available packages.

That said, if you are certain you want an older version of setup.exe, the only way to get it would be to find the file mirrored elsewhere. Simply google the specific version you want, and you should be able to easily find what you are looking for. download.cnet.com, for example, has many previous releases: [see for yourself](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3adownload.cnet.com+cygwin&oq=site%3adownload.cnet.com+cygwin&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...8289l15117l4l15221l35l35l15l0l0l4l381l5021l2-11j6l17l0.&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c2a3d8871f6dcd2c&biw=1241&bih=615).

In summary, there is no 'official' way to get previous Cygwin releases, so you will have to find a mirror of that specific release.

Comment: setup-legacy is a dead link.

Comment: Here's a working link as of now: http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/setup/legacy/setup-legacy.exe

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see this answer but ignore the parts about Postgres

https://serverfault.com/a/532412/123651

2. Install an old version if you have to. Someone maintains a historical archive of Cygwin versions.

   1. Browse the time stamp of the setup.ini file you need: http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html
   2. Copy the address of the folder (not index.html)
   3. Run `/setup-x86.exe -X` with the `-X` option to ignore setup signatures (they aren't archived).
   4. Paste the address into the dialog to choose your download site. You will then see a snapshot of packages available during that time.

Then pick the Cygwin base package to get an older version.

Comment: I still got a message: cygwin the current ini file is from a newer version, so the install does not go further

Comment: Show me a screencast.

Comment: The requested resource is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.

Answer (score -1):

Download any setup version from https://cygwin.com/setup/